# Get progress of derby database recovery process

Tags: eclipse-rcp, derby

I would like to create a progress bar that shows when the derby database of my elipse RCP applications is repairing itself on startup.

I read about how the general recovery proces of derby works: http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/recovery.html

Now I'm left trying to figure out if there are any hooks that I can use to show the progress of the recovery process. Are there any extensions point I could use?

Comment: I haven't seen such hooks. Does it really take a substantial amount of time to perform recovery on startup? Perhaps you should address that underlying problem, instead; a Derby database that is shut down cleanly should start back up almost instantly.

Comment: I'm already working on fixing the underlaying issue. You are right this is the main problem. If it is correctly shutdown it starts instantly yes but if not it can take up to a few minutes (Depends on the system it runs on). The application I'm running increases the database size about 70MB/hour so I guess its related to the amount of data.

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether calling `SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CHECKPOINT_DATABASE` with some frequency reduces the recovery time upon a dirty startup.

Comment: I will look into it once I get back to the source on monday. Thanks for your input!